# AllowOverride and RewriteCond/RewriteRule interactions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up a site running on Apache 2.4.16 to redirect all www URLs to non-www URLs. I'm using HTML5 Boilerplate's Apache configs to do this (as well as everything else they provide).

https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/dist/.htaccess

This happens on line 380, seen below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm using `Include` to add the whole file to my vhost config for the site, as well as an `AllowOverride All` for another `.htaccess` file at my doc root (same one that comes with Laravel 5):

**production.vhost.conf (relevant part)**

```
<Directory /var/www/hostname/production>
    AllowOverride All

    # Include H5BP server configs
    Include server-configs-apache/dist/.htaccess
</Directory>
```

**.htaccess (at doc root)**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, *almost* everything from H5BP's `.htaccess` was working, except for the redirect from www to non-www. After poking around I noticed that the redirect was only working when I'd remove `AllowOverride All` from the `<Directory>` block in the vhost. So the doc root `.htaccess` was somehow overriding the rewrite conditions.

I've actually already fixed my initial issue by moving the doc root `.htaccess` contents into the vhost file and removing the AllowOverride, but I'm more curious as to *why* this was happening; more specifically how AllowOverride interacts with RewriteCond and RewriteRule.

My hunch is that the `.htaccess` in my doc root was overriding the www to non-www redirect, but I'm not sure why that one specifically. For example, the http -> https redirect worked without issue (line 352 of H5BP, uncommented out in mine), it seemed to be just that one redirect. I didnt even think that those rules could be overridden since RewriteCond/RewriteRules feel unique to me.

If there are any, what are the rules that determine how an `.htaccess` can override a rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

> If there are any, what are the rules that determine how an .htaccess
>   can override a rewrite rule?

Conditions and rules don't dictate how .htaccess works. `AllowOverride` is what allows .htaccess usage.  If you have `AllowOverride All` then .htaccess is allowed, if you have `AllowOverride None`, then it's not and it will be ignored. In 2.4 `None` is the default.

.htaccess is per directory so it will take precedence if it's located in a directory that has rules applied as long as .htaccess file usage is allowed there. Which is confgiured in the server config in `VirtualHost` or `Directory` directives.

Also using an include for .htaccess in a vhost is a very bad configuration. If you have access to the vhost file or the config, you should create another config and include it with the .htaccess contents.

*You should not be using .htaccess files `at all` actually with access to the server config. See this apache recommendation on not using .htaccess.* 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when

Comment: My Include is for the html5 boilerplate server configs, it just happens to also be named .htaccess. I can change the name of it and get same results. Sorry if that wasnt clear.

It's my understanding that an .htaccess actually overrides directives when AllowOverride is All, so I was wondering how it might have been overwriting some of my rewrite rules

Comment: Ok I see. I wouldn't call it .htaccess. Reason being is that is the default name for the [AccessFileName](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#what) and you will probably create problems that way. And performance is better using server config. Change the name to something else. And it does override directives per directory. So as I mentioned what is in your .htaccess will take precendence over the config. But your current .htaccess rules don't contain anything that would conflict with redirecting to non www. So it's something else.

Comment: Yeah I switched everything to server config which did solve my issue, my question was more wondering why it was happening in the first place. The redirect started working when I moved the contents of the .htaccess at the doc root to the vhost config. So to me it looked like the .htaccess at the docroot was overriding some of my rewrite rules, which I didnt think was possible since they don't conflict as you mentioned.